# ctags basic usage

Tags: 14.04

I am Following tutorials on how to use `exuberant-ctags` on Ubuntu 14.04.
I run the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags
```

Then I `cd` into the root folder a project and run:

```
$ ctags -R .
```

I also tried

- `ctags -R *`
- `ctags -R <folder_name>`

in all cases ctags consumes all computer resources - locking up PC, and I need to kill the process, after which a `tags` file that is many gigabytes will be sitting in My current directory.
what is going wrong?

Update

As per @muru request, when I run `ctags -R .` inside a completely empty directory, newly created `ctags` file contains:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT       2       /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED       1       /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME      Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL       http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.9~svn20110310 //
```

Comment: And where is this current directory and what does it contain?

Comment: it is an otherwise empty directory created for testing ctags. i then installed some libraries  : grunt (via npm) twitter (via bower) and my IDE (phpstorm) added a .idea folder

Comment: Test on an actual empty directory. Or one that your IDE hasn't touched. Also inspect the contents of the tags file created (`head`, or `tail`, or `less`).

Comment: have updated answer with result using empty directory. `rm -rf .idea` folder and rerun `ctags -R .` still getting same problem. huge `tags` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @muru pointing me in the right direction, it seems the `grunt` packages (`grunt` and/or `grunt/less`) in the `node_modules` directory were causing the issue, I removed the grunt packages and now I am getting output that ostensibly seems correct!